# Cannot use unit in cloudwatch alarm via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am trying to create an AWS cloudwatch alarm using Terraform.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "rds_networkreceivethroughput" {
  alarm_name          = "rds_network_receive_throughput"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "5"
  metric_name         = "NetworkReceiveThroughput"
  namespace           = "AWS/RDS"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = "10"
  unit                = "Megabytes/Second"
  alarm_description   = "The incoming (Receive) network traffic on the DB instanceis greater than threshold"
  treat_missing_data  = "notBreaching"

  alarm_actions = [
    "${aws_sns_topic.my_sns.arn}",
  ]

  dimensions {
    "DBInstanceIdentifier" = "${var.rds_instance_identifier}"
  }
}
```

I was able to create the cloudwatch alarm, but the unit is not getting applied. The unit is applied was `10 Bytes/Second` instead of `10 Megabytes/Second`.
Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AWS RDS doesn't support Megabytes/second as a unit for `NetworkReceiveThroughput`, instead only supporting `Bytes/second`. You can read about the available options in the [Cloudwatch user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/rds-metricscollected.html).

That said I'm a little bit surprised that the AWS API didn't just error on you instead of selecting the only possible unit.

Comment: But the configuration got updated saying  `"unit": "Megabytes/Second"` in the history tab in alarms.